# How to solve the equation for LHS value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to solve the following equation using sympy library.

I = -0.53V + 65.88

I have been using the following line of code:

```
from sympy import *
V = Symbol('vi')
I = -0.5*vi + 65.88
solve(V - 5, I)
```

But, it returns me an empty list. I am aware that this code was designed for finding the unknown on RHS, but I don't know the syntax for finding the unknown value on the LHS.

Comment: What do you want to find? The value of V that makes the expression 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `I` that way makes it an Addition, not a Symbol; you can evaluate it but not solve in terms of it (see [Equals signs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs) in the Sympy docs).

Instead try

```
import sympy as sp

# create the symbols
V, I = sp.Symbols("V I")

# set up an equality statement
eq = sp.Eq(I, sp.Float("-0.53") * V + sp.Float("65.88"))

# try to reorder the equation to find solutions for V
sp.solve(eq, V)   # returns a single solution,  [-1.88679245283019*I + 124.301886792453]

# solve numerically for V == 5
eq.subs(V, sp.Float("5"))   # returns Eq(I, 63.2300000000000)
```